# Extract multiple "quoted" words from cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Having trouble devising a formula to do the following... any help is appreciated

I have a cell of text with an unknown number of Double Quoted words. I need the quoted words extracted, then listed in another cell (either on new line or concatenated with comma/ semi-colon)

Sample Text:
My "dog" ate my "apple" when I looked "away"

Required Output:
dog, apple, away

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: In fact, you can also use the "text to columns" function, each "" as a conversion symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your version of Excel,

For entries in separate cells:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'""')]"),"""","")
```

For entries in the same cell:

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",,SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'""')]"),"""",""))
```

The formula just looks for a single, double-quote in the space separated words. If that is not specific enough, a more complex formula could be created, but VBA with regular expressions would probably be easier to implement.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function DontQuoteMe(s As String) As String
    Dim q As String, arr, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim hr As String
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    q = Chr(34)
    hr = Chr(10)
    DontQuoteMe = ""
    If InStr(s, q) = 0 Then Exit Function
    arr = Split(" " & s & " ", q)
    i = 1
    
    For Each a In arr
        If wf.IsEven(i) Then
            DontQuoteMe = DontQuoteMe & hr & a
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next a
    DontQuoteMe = Mid(DontQuoteMe, 2)
End Function
```

[image]